# How to iterate over table and get open the tab that satisfies a condition

Tags: python, html, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I need to iterate over a table to fetch values of "GST Invoice No." and open the "View Invoice" table of only those invoice number whose third place has digit 2.

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait 
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC

driver = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path=r'D:/Chrome driver/chromedriver.exe') # Get local session(use webdriver.Chrome() for chrome) 

driver.get("URL")



WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.XPATH, "//input[@id='PNRId']"))).send_keys("SHFYGW")
WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//input[@id='GstRetrievePageInteraction']"))).click()


#print(toJourney.find_element_by_xpath('/tbody/tr/td[2]/ul'))
```

How to proceed with iterating the table? I tried with the following but it gives only one value

```
uls = driver.find_elements(By.CLASS_NAME, "gst-invoice-list.list-inline")
```

Ho do I iterate to open only the one's with digit 2 at it's third place?

Comment: Hi what seems to be the problem?

Comment: Hi, for different PNRS the invoice's are scattered and not arranged in a specific order. I want to open those invoice's whose GST Invoice No has digit 2 in it's 3rd place. How to loop over that and fetch those invoice?

Comment: You can use a xpath with ul[class='gst-invoice-list list-inline']/li than a regex /text()='' to match.

Comment: Will this check for all the gst numbers?

Comment: You need use a /text()='' after that  with a check for the digit 2 in the 3rd palce.

Comment: I can use the regex as we normally use it and also do we need to write anything to the right of equals?

Comment: I am not understanding how write it between the xpath

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The table contains the GST invoice number is taking some time to load the 'GST Invoice No.'. Apply some wait before reading the data to compare. Check below code the extract the invoice no and compare 3rd digit and click on the 'view invoice' link to view invoice'

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC

driver = webdriver.Chrome()

driver.get("URL")

WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//input[@id='PNRId']"))).send_keys("SHFYGW")
WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//input[@id='GstRetrievePageInteraction']"))).click()

WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.CLASS_NAME, "gst-invoice-list.list-inline")))

elements = driver.find_elements(By.CLASS_NAME, "gst-invoice-list.list-inline")

for ele in elements:
    eleText = ele.find_element_by_tag_name("li").text
    if eleText[2]=='2':
        print(eleText)
        #ele.find_element(By.ID, 'ViewInvoice').click()
        driver.execute_script("arguments[0].click()", ele.find_element(By.ID, 'ViewInvoice'));
        #break

driver.quit()
```

Comment: Hi Dilip, The above code gives ```ElementClickInterceptedException: element click intercepted:``` I tried with ```ele.find_element(By.XPATH, 'li[2]/a[1]').click()``` still I get the same error

Comment: @ShwetaSave - This code search for the first occurrence and click on the **ViewInvoice**, which will be opened in new tab and execution will come out of for loop. If you want to  `ViewInvoice` for all the occurance than you need to use getWindowHandles to achieve the same. `ElementClickInterceptedException: element click intercepted:` error you must be getting because a image on that page will get the click when you check for other `ViewInvoice` button which is being overlapped by that footer image.

Comment: It is not opening for the first occurrence it encounters.

Comment: You removed that `break` statement?

Comment: Yes, but then I did add it.

Comment: Keep the same code from my answer and run need to check if its working or not? And check if its printing the 'GST invoice no' on console.

Comment: And I want to get all the invoices whose 3rd digit is 2, but the second invoice is not opened so, why do we need to do getWindowHandles?

Comment: It's printing the number, but not opening invoice.

Comment: One more question when you click on View Invoice and invoice get opened in new tab there you may want to perform some operation or do data extraction, for that purpose you have to switch to that tab and after completing all the operation you have to return back to previous window and repeat the same till the 'GST invoice no' have 2 and 3rd place.

Comment: Code updated check now. Added JavaScript executor to avoid the click issue.Now this will work for all the matches.

Answer (score 0):

Without the regex currently just finding by xpath.

```
driver.implicitly_wait(5)
uls = driver.find_elements_by_xpath("//ul[@class='gst-invoice-list list-inline']//li")
for url in uls:
    if url.text[2]=='2': #^..2 would be a simple regex for digit 2 on 3rd index
         print (url.text)
```

Displays the following

```
MH2192004AA58892
MP2192004AA05359
```

Comment: To open only these 2 invoice I am now supposed to use the url in place of driver, right?

Comment: You can pretty much look at dilips answer and figure out what he did. Except using the break.